# Issue with API Versioning .NET Core 2.2 UnsupportedApiVersion

Tags: api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I am creating an API and need to have versioning done in it. I am using package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning 3.1.3

My StartUp.cs is as follows

In ConfigureServices

```
services.AddApiVersioning(o => {
            o.ReportApiVersions = true;
            o.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
            o.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
        });

        services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

My 2 controllers on which I want to have versioning done are as below

```
namespace JWTWithRefresh.Areas.V1.CMS
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ApiVersion("1.0")]
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    public class AppController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult GetApp()
        {
            return Ok("This is from API V1");
        }
    }
}
```

and another controller is as below

```
namespace JWTWithRefresh.Areas.V2.CMS
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ApiVersion("2.0")]
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    public class AppController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult GetApp()
        {
        return Ok("This is from API V2");
        }
    }
}
```

The response I get when I make a call is as below

Endpoint = https://localhost:5001/api/App/GetApp?api-version=1.0

Response =

```
{
    "error": {
             "code": "UnsupportedApiVersion",
             "message": "The HTTP resource that matches the request URI 'https://localhost:5001/api/App/GetApp' is not supported.",
             "innerError": null
    }
}
```

Please guide me in fixing this issue if anyone has gone through the same.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look here and see if this solves it: https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/issues/437

Comment: Thanks you hit the bulls eye. Solved my problem.

Comment: Mark it as answered

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else having the problem, I solved it by following suggestion from LGSon in comments above:

Solution 1:

```
Add [ApiController] in Controller
```

Solution 2:

Disable API Behavior

```
services.AddApiVersioning( options => options.UseApiBehavior = false );
```

Answer (score 0):

Change Route attribute like this

```
[Route("v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]/[action]")]
```

and endpoint = https://localhost:5001/api/App/v1/GetApp or https://localhost:5001/api/App/v2/GetApp.

for more: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETCoreRESTfulWebAPIVersioningMadeEasy.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The issue can come if you dont change the version from the dropdown in the swagger ui and in the api call, you change the version number and execute.

Make sure you change the version number from the dropdown [swagger api version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvasN.png), before giving the api version number in the api call.

[version in api call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SBge.png)